# Using opensaml on android

Tags: android, single-sign-on, saml

at the moment i am trying to write an android app, which will be able to create a SAML response and send this response to a server. 
For this approch i am using opensaml-2.4.1.jar and android 2.2. My problem is, when eclipse is building my project i got warnings like:

> Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (org.apache.commons.collections.DoubleOrderedMap$5) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

There are a lot of this warnings.

Further more i got some of theses messages in LogCat:

> DEBUG/dalvikvm(2857): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;': multiple definitions

I dont understand the meaning of these warnings.
Can somebody help me with that?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the correct java compiled version for Android (Java 1.5 +). If you intend to include libraries, the jars compiled in 1.4 or less will have caused this error.